# $\theta: R[x] \rightarrow R,$ $\ker(\theta) = (x)$ and it's a principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring. Show that the map $\theta : R[x] \rightarrow R$ given by $\theta(a_0+a_1 x+\cdots+a_nx^n) = a_0$ is a ring homomorphism. Show that $ker  (\theta)$ is the principal ideal $(x)$. Here $R[x] = \{a_0+a_1 x+\cdots+a_nx^n \mid a_i \in R\}$, the ring of polynomials, and $(x) = \{ax\mid a\in R\}= xR[x]$, the ideal generated by $x$.

I already showed that this was a ring homomorphism, but I don't know how to show that $\ker(\theta) = (x)$. Obviously

$\ker(\theta) = \{a \in R[x] \mid \theta(a) = 0\} =\{a_0+a_1 x + \cdots + a_nx^n \mid a_0 = 0, a_i \in R, i\neq0\}$

and

$$(x) = \{ax\mid a\in R[x]\}= xR[x].$$

One thing that I was confused about was if $R[x]$ are polynomials that are  upto degree $n$ wouldn't $(x)$ contain polynomials upto degree $n+1$? I could see that the first term in each elements of these sets are have the same deree since for any $a = a_0+a_1 x+\cdots+a_nx^n$, $x(a_0+\cdots+a_nx^n) = a_0x+\cdots+a_nx^{n+1}$. If the degrees were the same, I was just going to say that since they contain the exact elements $\ker(\theta) = (x)$, but I'm not sure that'd be enough. What would be a good strategy to show this?

Comment: Because $n$ is never quantified anywhere, I would assume that a $\forall n\geq0$ is appended to the end of the definition of $\theta$, along with a $\forall a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n$.

Comment: So basically $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

Comment: Polynomials of degree up to $n$ do not form a ring! :) Your definition of $R[x]$ is definitely wrong.

Comment: Your definition of generate is wrong $$(x)=\{qx| q \in R[x]\}$$

Comment: $$R[X]=\{a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n|  a_j \in R, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cleary that $$(x) \subset ker(\theta)$$, conversely if $$f \in ker(\theta)$$ write $$f=q.x+a_0$$ with $$a_0 \in R$$ thus $$\theta(f)=a_0=0$$ thus $$f=qx$$.